# Mongo DBaaS Data in Transit Security

Tags: mongodb

I've been looking at setting up a MongoDB as a Service on Mongo HQ/Compose.io or some other service.

From what I can gather the major security hole is the data in transit.  Mongo doesn't support native driver SSL by default, and most DBaaS providers don't offer it standard.

It seems to me that it is a big security risk.  Am I wrong here?

thanks.

Comment: Yup. If the data isn't encrypted in flight, I suppose someone could listen in and grab it. If security is important to you, you should bear the extra expense to manage your own MongoDB or find a hosting company that supports SSL for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, That is correct. MongoDB does not support SSL by default and few DbaaS providers don't usually offer one. You might have to manage mongodb yourself. The easiest way I guess is to docker it up.

Btw, Did you check out CloudBoost.io (https://www.cloudboost.io). We have SSL on our API's and have all the features which MongoDB has and more.

P.S : I work at CloudBoost.io